# How to specify fps (frame rate) when streaming video with uv4l?

Tags: streaming-video, uv4l

I run the following command:
`uv4l --driver uvc --device-id '0458:7081'`
It seems to be working, but I've no idea how to define lower fps to reduce traffic. The [manual](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=16) didn't help.
The distro is Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v4l2-ctl` in the `V4L2` tools collection to set the frame rate to one allowed value.

Comment: Thanks. The following commands helped:
`v4l2-ctl --set-fmt-video=width=1280,height=720,pixelformat=1 && v4l2-ctl --set-parm=8`
where pixelformat was determined by:
`v4l2-ctl --list-formats`

Comment: Unfortunately I obtained that v4l2-ctl settings sometimes are being ignored by uv4l. Moreover, uv4l removes module 'uvcvideo' so after rebooting 'v4l2-ctrl' can't be applied until the module loaded manually (because there is no file '/dev/video0').
Also there is `--configuration` param available for uv4l uvc driver. What syntax of arguments for this param?

Comment: you are mixing stuff: uvcvideo is the kernel driver, while uv4l-uvc is the userspace driver. they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: So what's the actual parameter for frame rate in v4l2-ctl?

Comment: For those wondering, `v4l2-ctl --set-parm=8` is the one that sets the frame rate. In this case, it's 8.0 FPS.